# 'Node' object is not callable

Tags: python, linked-list, stack

I have the following code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
class linkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = None
    def isempty(self):
        return self.top== None
    def push(self,data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        #if self.top ==None:
        #    self.top= new_node
         #   return
        new_node.next = self.top
        self.top = new_node
    def pop(self):
        if self.top ==None:
            print('underflow comdition')
            return
        temp = self.top
        self.top = self.top.next
        return temp.data
    def top(self):
        if self.isempty():
            print('empty stack')
            return

        return self.top.data
    def printstack(self):
        if self.isempty():
            return
        temp = self.top
        print('stack from top')
        while temp != None:
            print(temp.data)
            temp = temp.next

llist = linkedList()
llist.push(5)
llist.push(7)
llist.push(9)
llist.push(11)
llist.push(13)
llist.push(15)
llist.push(17)
llist.pop()
llist.pop()
llist.top()
llist.pop()
llist.push('oolala')
llist.printstack()
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-16-a71ab451bb35> in <module>
     47 llist.pop()
     48 llist.pop()
---> 49 llist.top()
     50 llist.pop()
     51 llist.push('oolala')

TypeError: 'Node' object is not callable
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: Garvit - I removed the unnecessary text from your post and tried to make it into an actual question... can you please [edit] it further to explain what you're trying to do and what results you expect please? Also - keep it civil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrote the attribute `top`: it cannot be both a variable *and* a method.

First you define it as a method:

```
def top(self):
    ...
```

But, later, you overwrite that with a `top` node attribute:

```
    self.top = new_node
```

`top` is now a `Node`, and you can't call a node.

I recommend that you change the method name; as a general practice, methods should be verbs, as you've done with `push` and `pop`.

```
def show_top(self):
    if self.isempty():
        print('empty stack')
        return
    return self.top.data

...

llist.pop()
llist.show_top()
llist.pop()
llist.push('oolala')
llist.printstack()
```